# jupyter notebook / python crashes when loading csv from GCS

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, jupyter-notebook, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datalab

I found bizarre behavior in Jupyter notebook, when I load my own csv. On one GCE it works, on the other it works fine. Probably, I need to set up my instance better - maybe, I've missed something trivial here.

My code goes like this (look below) - most is basically tutorial stuff. The bucket and filenames are good because it works in different instance. The new GCE has more RAM and more CPUs. But I don't think this should be the problem. Any ideas what could go wrong? (the issue is on python 2 and 3)

```
from google.datalab import Context
import google.datalab.bigquery as bq
import google.datalab.storage as storage
import pandas as pd
try:
  from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
  from io import BytesIO as StringIO
%%gcs read --object gs://ls_w/tmax_out_save.csv --variable bla  # crashes here
```

I've also tried this

```
bla = storage.Object('ls_w', 'tmax_out_save.csv').read_stream() # crashes here
```

Comment: Can you provide the error? There's little we can do to help without the full context.

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you error. It was usual kernel restart... It was very frustrating as I couldn't trace the error. I have resolved the issue by creating a new instance. I guess there was an error, when I created the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by creating a new instance. I guess there was an error, when I created the instance.